# What is the nature of the series of the general term: $u_n = \frac{e - (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n}{n^{\frac{3}{2}} - [n^{\frac{3}{2}}] + n} $.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> What is the nature of the series of the general term:
>
> $u_n = \frac{e - (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n}{n^{\frac{3}{2}} - [n^{\frac{3}{2}}] + n} $.

[] is the step function.

---

Using the inequality of the step function I found:

$\frac{e - (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n}{n + 1} < u_n \leq \frac{e - (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n}{n} $

By computing the limit of the right and left terms I found: $\lim_{n \to + \infty} \frac{e - (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n}{n + 1} = \lim \frac{e - (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n}{n} = 0$ which is not helpful.

How can I find the nature of the series?

Comment: The denominator is equivalent to $n$ and find an equivalent of the numerator by writing $(1+1/n)^n = \exp (n \ln(1+1/n))$

Comment: @AlexL. I have found that it is converging after finding the equivalent of the equivalent sequence. Thank you for your help.